# Issue where WP Featured Image will not display

Tags: posts, post-thumbnails, images

The code I'm using, is outside of WordPress i.e.

```
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require('blog/wp-blog-header.php');    
global $wpdb;
```

The code that I'm trying to display the post thumbnail (the set featured image) is:

```
if(has_post_thumbnail($post->ID)){
    echo "has a thumb";
    get_the_post_thumbnail();
    the_post_thumbnail();
    the_post_thumbnail('medium');
    wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id());
    wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ));
} else {
    echo "no thumb";
}
```

Now it does does correctly display if there is a thumb or not, but doesn't return the thumb file name or anything at all. I've tried all methods I could find and nothing is returned, nor is there any errors returned.

Suggestions, thoughts?

Comment: Can I ask why you're using that code outside of WordPress? What exactly IS displayed/returned?

Comment: I don't want to make use of their template system, as I'm simply using the posts/categories of WP with another system. Nothing is returned/displayed other than "has a thumb" or "no thumb" which is accurate with each post.

Comment: Why not just use WordPress for everything? One can accomplish a vast number of things using WordPress without even touching the 'blogging' part.

Comment: It's a giant system, custom build and integrating it into WP would be a giant waste of time which is not in abundance right now as per this project.

Comment: i would stringly suggest calling `wp-load.php` instead of `wp-blog-header.php`. had a few problems lately with code using the latter. also, you have to echo the `wp_get_attachment_image_src['0']`, as this returns an Array, and does not print out the details.

Comment: Can you expand the code above so that we can see the post loop? Or at least where $post is assigned/instantiated

Comment: What do the following contain? `$thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID )` and, assuming that has valid output, `wp_get_attachment_image( $thumbnail_id )`

Comment: Using wp-load didn't change anything, also echoing out the wp_get didn't return anything either. My current code is http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/91x-68t

Comment: you can't expect to just include part of wp and have everything just work.  id be extremely surprised if this does work.  i would recommend if you insist on doing this outside of wp, don't even use their functions at all, just connect to db and get what you need.  all the info you need is im posts and postmeta to simply display a featured image.

Answer (score 0):

Let's examine the differences between the *working* and the *not-working* code:

- **Working**: `has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID )`
- **Not Working**: `get_the_post_thumbnail();`

The only difference I see is that you're passing the `$postID` explicitly to the working function, and *not* passing it to the *non-working* function. So, try this:

```
get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, 'medium' );
```

You can `var_dump()` or `echo` it to verify whether or not you're getting the correct data returned.

Comment: Using your new code (with echo), returns nothing. With var_dump() returns this  thumbstring(0) "". Odd since there is a set featured image for that post..

Answer (score 0):

`get_the_post_thumbnail`, and `wp_get_attachment_image_src` return their output, they don't echo it out.

In this case to get the url for a given size:

```
$image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ),'thumbnail');
$url = $image[0];
$width = $image[1];
$height = $image[2];
```

*it may be noted that the thumbnail size will be used if none is specified but I've added it to be precise*

If you're in need of further clarification on exactly what is being returned by those functions, and want something stark and outright blatantly visible, I'd suggest something such as:

```
$value = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ));
wp_die('<pre>'.print_r($value,true).'</pre>');
```

Though I would recommend you use `error_log` rather than `wp_die` and look at the error log in a text editor, as wp_die is not something you want in production code

edit: -_- debug all the things!!

```
?>
<pre>
post ID : "<?php $post->ID; ?>"<br>
has_post_thumbnail : "<?php if(has_post_thumbnail($post->ID)){ echo 'true'; }else {echo 'false'; } ?>"<br>
thumb ID : "<?php get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ); ?>"<br>
thumb ID null? : "<?php if(get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ) == null) { echo 'yes'; } else { echo 'no'; } ?>"<br>
wp_get_attachment_image_src : "<?php print_r(wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID )),false)?>"
</pre>
<?php
```

Comment: The wp_die code above returns nothing at all, error_log returns nothing as well.

Comment: show me what the updated code I posted gives you ( using copy paste, not descriptive prose )

Comment: Returns http://pastebin.com/mFghnp2n

Comment: can you do it again but this time put `global $post;` beforehand?

Comment: Done, exact same thing is returned as my pastebin...

Comment: hmmm so until you fix the problem of $post->ID being empty/null/etc we aren't going anywhere, where are you getting $post from? Can we see your post loop?

Comment: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/91x-68t

Comment: aha, I strongly recommend you never use `query_posts`, it modifies the main query meaning there are always 2 queries happening. Here, there is no main query to modify, instead use a `WP_Query` object to do your query

Comment: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/0db-r4s

Comment: Still no attachment is returned, same info returned as previously. any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
echo '<img src="'.get_the_post_thumbnail().'" />';
```